# Urban Airship with marmalade SDK

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com, marmalade

I`m trying to integrate Urban Airship in my application. Some error
happened during UAirship:takeOff. I wrote to FAQ, but nobody answered me.

I `m using the following code:

```
NSLog(@"Starting airship...");
UAConfig *config = [UAConfig defaultConfig];
config.developmentAppKey = @"mydevelopmentkey";
config.developmentAppSecret = @"mydevelopmentsecretkey";
config.inProduction = FALSE;
[UAirship takeOff:config];
NSLog(@"Airship started");
```

Then, when calling takeOff method, application crashes and I get the
following output:

```
hero[3457] Warning: Starting airship...
hero[3457] Warning: [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 163] Production App Key
is not valid.
hero[3457] Warning: [W] -[UAConfig validate] [Line 167] Production App
Secret is not valid.
hero[3457] Warning: [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 151] App
Key: <removed>
hero[3457] Warning: [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 152] App
Secret: <removed>
hero[3457] Warning: [I] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 153]
Server: https://device-api.urbanairship.com
hero[3457] Warning: [D] -[UAirship configureUserAgent] [Line 296] Setting
User-Agent for UA requests to hero 2.28.11.42.57 (iPod touch; iPhone OS
6.1.3; UALib 2.1.0; <removed>; ru_RU)
hero[3457] Warning: [D] void
PrintReachabilityFlags(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, const char *) [Line 79]
Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
hero[3457] Warning: [D] +[UAirship executeUnsafeTakeOff:] [Line 186]
Deleting the UA device ID
hero[3457] Error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot
 be nil (key: gena)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32d792a3 0x3aa5d97f 0x32cdb313 0x4ef85 0x4ee27 0x4f877 0x490b7 0x48aaf
0x3ae744b7 0x3ae7a3f7 0x48a8b 0x43760 0x43484 0xd95c0 0xe7020 0x336900f5
0x32d4e683 0x32d4dee9 0x32d4ccb7 0x32cbfebd 0x32cbfd49 0x368872eb
0x34bd5301 0xead4c 0x2e214)
```

I develop a game using Marmalade SDK. It provides the ability to write native "extensions" (the libraries of native code, that can be called from the c++ code). The problem is, that extensions don`t support all the app delegate events. For example, in Urban Airship sample code takeOff method is called from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. But extensions are initialised later, than this message occured in appdelegate, so it can`t be handled.
I try to call the code above as a method from the main thread. But the result is error to.

Can anybody help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you're setting `nil` in `setObjectForkey`. Check the argument properly. We've added urban airship into our marmalade projects too, so I am sure that's not Urban Airship's bug.

Comment: Did you find a way to implement didFinishLaunchWithOptions in extension? Or you just called a method with [UAirship takeOff] somewhere in your application?

Comment: If you mean 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' method than I guess that's tricky, since it's called on UIApplicationDelegate only. You can instead use UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification. Check Marmalade's source for push - notifications here - https://github.com/marmalade/s3eIOSNotifications/blob/master/source/iphone/s3eIOSNotifications_platform.mm
   They have the code you might be interested in, although much of the code is commented out, but you can still find it useful.